# The nonparametric estimation in generalized regression model

Tags: asymptotics, nonparametric-regression, nadaraya-watson

Let $Y_t \in \mathbb{R}$ be a response variable and $X_t$ a $d$-dimensional explanatory variable. Assume we observe the process that $(X_1, Y_1), \cdots, (X_n, Y_n)$.
\begin{equation}
    Y_{t} = \mu(X_{t})+\sigma(X_{t})\varepsilon_{t}, \quad t\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
Then the NW estimator for $\mu(\cdot)$ and $\sigma^2(\cdot)$ are
\begin{equation*}
    \hat{\mu}(x) = \frac{1}{n \bar{w}(x; h)} \sum_{t = 1}^n w(x ; t, h) Y_t,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \hat\sigma^2(x) = \frac{1}{n \bar{w}(x; h)} \sum_{t = 1}^n w (x ; t, h) \big( Y_t - \hat{\mu} (x)\big)^2,
\end{equation*}
respectively, where
\begin{equation*}
    \bar{w}(x ; h) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{t = 1}^n w(x ; t, h), \qquad w(x ; t, h) = \frac{1}{h^d} H\left( \frac{X_t - x}{h}\right)
\end{equation*}
is the $d$-dimensional kernel density estimator of $f(x)$, the marginal density of $\{X_t\}$.

Now I want to know the properties of the two estimators, like the asymptotic expansion of $\hat{\mu}(x) - \mu(x)$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2(x) - \sigma^2(x)$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

There does exist some articles regarding the asymptotic normality for $\hat{\sigma}^2(x) - \sigma^2(x)$ in the setting of the local linear method, see [Fan and Qao](http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/6635/1/Efficient_estimation_of_conditional_variance_functions_in_stochastic_regression%28LSERO%29.pdf). However, I cannot find any useful literature for the asymptotic expansion of $\hat{\mu}(x) - \mu(x)$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2(x) - \sigma^2(x)$ in the setting of NW estimators.

Could anyone help me? Thanks so much!

Comment: What makes asymptotics relevant, since you would be applying the method to finite samples?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Yeah. I forgot adding the condition that $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: That doesn't come close to answering my question.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Sorry... I may not get your point. Do you mean I should state the regular conditions to let the NW-estimators make sense?

Comment: No. You should validate performance on realistic sample sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asymptotic expression for $(\hat{m} - m)(x)$ is presented in the Appendix of [Fan and Qao](http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/6635/1/Efficient_estimation_of_conditional_variance_functions_in_stochastic_regression%28LSERO%29.pdf). So this question is meaningless.